# Keytabs generation issue

Tags: centos, encryption, redhat-enterprise-linux, kerberos, windows-authentication

I have troubles while creating `keytabs` for user.
`Keytabs` are working only when I have `rc4-hmac` encryption enabled

```
[root@host ~]# klist -kte test_user.keytab_rc4
Keytab name: FILE:test_user.keytab_rc4
KVNO Timestamp           Principal
---- ------------------- ------------------------------------------------------
   0 09/01/2018 14:54:07 test_user@testdomain.dev (arcfour-hmac)
[root@host]# kinit -V -kt test_user.keytab_rc4 test_user@testdomain.dev
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5_1015
Using principal: test_user@testdomain.dev
Using keytab: test_user.keytab_rc4
Authenticated to Kerberos v5
[root@host ~]# klist 
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5_1015
Default principal: test_user@testdomain.dev

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
10/08/2018 09:10:40  10/08/2018 19:10:40  krbtgt/testdomain.dev@testdoman.dev
        renew until 10/15/2018 09:10:40
[root@host ~]# kdestroy
```

If I'm trying to authenticate with `keytab` that contains any other encryption

```
[root@host ~]# klist -kte test_user.keytab_aes256
Keytab name: FILE:test_user.keytab_aes256
KVNO Timestamp           Principal
---- ------------------- ------------------------------------------------------
   0 09/01/2018 14:57:07 test_user@testdomain.dev (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
```

Or multiple encryption types

```
[root@host ~]# klist -kte test_user.keytab_rc4_aes256
Keytab name: FILE:test_user.keytab_rc4_aes256
KVNO Timestamp           Principal
---- ------------------- ------------------------------------------------------
   0 09/01/2018 14:57:07 test_user@testdomain.dev (arcfour-hmac)
   0 09/01/2018 14:57:07 test_user@testdomain.dev (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
[root@host ~]# kinit -V -kt test_user.keytab_rc4_aes256 test_user@testdomain.dev
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5_1015
Using principal: test_user@testdomain.dev
Using keytab: test_user.keytab_rc4_aes256
kinit: Preauthentication failed while getting initial credentials
```

it fails

All `keytabs` where created with same `ktutil` from CentOS:

```
[root@host ~]# ktutil
ktutil: add_entry -password -p test_user@testdomain.dev -k 0 -e arcfour-hmac
Password for test_user@testdomain.dev:
ktutil: wkt test_user.keytab_rc4
```

- Kerberos Server: Microsoft Active Directory 2012 with latest updates
- Tested encryption types that are **not working** :

  - `des3-cbc-sha1`
  - `aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96`
  - `aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96`
  - `dec-cbc-md5`
- Kerberos client: CentOS 7.4 with latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

First, all enctypes except *arcfour-hmac* use the realm name as part of the key salt. To derive the correct key from password, you must use *exactly* the same realm as the KDC uses. This usually means it needs to be **uppercase** (despite UPNs being lowercase).

Additionally, `aes128-cts…` and `aes256-cts…` enctypes may need to be [enabled per account](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2011/05/30/windows-configurations-for-kerberos-supported-encryption-type/) (and possibly globally in the domain controller as well) – see the linked Microsoft documentation.

As for DES: `des-cbc…` **must not** be used: single-DES is trivial to crack even on a PC. (On the other hand, Triple-DES `des3-cbc…` is simply not supported by Windows Server.)

(arcfour-hmac simply uses the NTLM password hash as its "key"; it was retrofitted to Kerberos. Therefore its keysalt does not include the realm.)